# Cocoalumberjack check if there is a logger

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, cocoalumberjack

I'm writing a framework for iOS and i use Cocoalumberjack for logging system.
In my code i write

`[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];`

to add a new logger.

If the user want to use Cocoalumberjack and call the same code the result is that Cocoalumberjack has two loggers, so every row will be printed twice.

I need a way to check inside my framework if DDTYLogger is already configured.

I saw inside the implementation that there is a private static variable to store all loggers

```
// An array used to manage all the individual loggers.
// The array is only modified on the loggingQueue/loggingThread.
static NSMutableArray *loggers;
```

maybe i can add a class method to return this array?

any advices?

Comment: Hey there!. Did you find an elegant solution to this issue, without hacking DDLog ?.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found any solution :(

Comment: Just in case you might find it useful, i ended up writing a custom logger, and dropped CocoaLumberjack for good. Source here https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/blob/develop/Simperium/SPLogger.h and here https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/blob/develop/Simperium/SPLogger.m

Comment: Although it doesn't offer the exact same functionalities as CocoaLumberjack, i've just tailored it down to our needs, and got rid of several kLOC in the process.